# Force the user to type-in only the values contained in the comboBoxItems Collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I just found a post on this site where the answerer has tried to answer a similar question. The link to the post is : [WPF ComboBox with IsEditable=“True” - How can I indicate that no match was found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609847/wpf-combobox-with-iseditable-true-how-can-i-indicate-that-no-match-was-found)

So, I tried to follow answer no. 1 Topic no.4 by user1234567. I ended up with the errors.

1) List does not contain Definition for ElementAt. On the line below :

```
if(textBox.Text != "" && items.ElementAt(i).StartsWith(textBox.Text))
```

I tried to solve that error by using the below line :

```
if(textBox.Text != "" && items[i].StartsWith(textBox.Text))
```

So, all the compile time errors goes away.

2) I get Runtime error on the below mentioned line :

```
items.Add(((ComboBoxItem)cbEffectOn.Items.GetItemAt(i)).Content.ToString());
```

The error says : `Cannot convert string to ComboBoxItem.`

If anybody of you have a better solution or can solve the above error please suggest.

**Update** :

Here is the XAML for the comboBox :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbEffectOn" IsEditable="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EffectName, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" 
            Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" KeyUp="myComboBox_KeyUp"/>
```

**Update 2** :

Here is the solution to the second problem:

I Tried to Cast a `string` to `ComboBoxItem` at first attempt. But now I know that all the items in the `ComboBox` are `string`s so I tried the below code and it worked :

```
items.Add(cbEffectOn.Items.GetItemAt(i).ToString());
```

Comment: Show us your XAML code.

Comment: I have updated my question. If you need all the XAML code then please comment.

Comment: not sure what your problem is with the answer that you were trying to use, I just copied and pasted it into a blank WPF project and it works fine with **no** errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get errors like you have, you can follow this simple advice to fix them. Your first error said that *`List` does not contain definition for `ElementAt`*. To fix this, go to the MSDN website and search for '`ElementAt` method'... in fact, you can even just search for that in any search engine and you should see an MSDN page at the top of the results... in this case, the [`Enumerable.ElementAt<TSource>` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) page.

Clicking on the link will take you to that page where you will see that the `ElementAt` method is in the `System.Linq` namespace, so the next thing to do is to check if you have added this to your code or not:

```
using System.Linq;
```

For the next error, *Cannot convert `string` to `ComboBoxItem`*, all you need to do is to look at your code:

```
items.Add(((ComboBoxItem)cbEffectOn.Items.GetItemAt(i)).Content.ToString());
```

You're clearly trying to cast something to a `ComboBoxItem`... but the error says it's a `string`. If we look again, we can see the `ToString()` method, which converts a value into a `string`... so maybe we should remove that?

```
items.Add(((ComboBoxItem)cbEffectOn.Items.GetItemAt(i)).Content);
```

Of course, that might not work either, depending on what exactly you have in your `Content` property. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion to look at msdn. That solved my problem by using System.Linq namespace at top of the document. But the second solution is not working. If I find anything related to that problem I will update here. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have found the solution to the second problem and I edited your answer for that.

Comment: It appears that your edit was rejected by reputed members because it is generally not a good idea to add new information to other people's posts. As such, I've taken the liberty to copy your edit and add it to your question. In future, it is preferable on this website that you either add updates to your own question or add your own answer, but don't worry, it's not a problem.